# Gap between UINavigationBar and the UINavigationController's content

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Having a contained (embedded) UINavigationController that can be dragged up to fill the screen, I discovered a weird bug. Precisely in the moment the navigation controller covered the whole screen, its main view resized and a gap of about 20 points appeared in between that view and the navigation bar.

It [appears](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/61507315630/wrestling-with-status-bars-and-navigation-bars-on) that this is an "intended" behavior in UINavigationController. But how do you get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of trying to find a solution (and even reading that there is no way to circumvent this), I found a solution that works well enough.

In my UINavigationController subclass I added the following override:

```
override public func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();

    if self.view.frame.size.height == Screen.height {
        for childVC in childViewControllers {
            childVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, navigationBar.frame.size.height, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - navigationBar.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Screen.height is unknown... Use of unresolved identifier. any new syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I think the 20 pixel is taken by the `UIStatusBar`. If you are using an xib file or storyboard with auto-layout you can set the top constraint to top layout guide so that the 20 pixel difference is handled correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly difference now. Perhaps some syntax changes, but this did it for me! Yeah!! Thanks @Lukas Kalinski

```
override public func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();

        if self.view.frame.size.height == UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height {
            for childVC in childViewControllers {
                childVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, navigationBar.frame.size.height, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - navigationBar.frame.size.height);
            }
        }
    }
```